# .css jquery bordercolor messes with css input:focus setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, input, focus

Got a question for some jQuery wizard who might stumble upon this.

When I use border-left-color, for example, to set a color for an input element using jquery, and when this input element has `input:focus{ border-color: somecolor; }` in the css file, jquery destroys the input:focus setting. When input gets focus, it stays the color I set it to using jQuery.

Is this a bug?

And if not, how can I prevent this from happening? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery `.css` is stronger than the definition in your CSS file because it adds inline styles.

You should add `!important` to the `:focus` css definition.

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AVPHV/)

> When using .css() as a setter, jQuery modifies the element's style property.
>    For example, **$('#mydiv').css('color', 'green')** is equivalent to **document.getElementById('mydiv').style.color = 'green'**.

[`.css` docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: Worked perfectly. I don't understand why I didn't think of that.